# SqlDataSource Insert code behind variable

Tags: asp.net, .net, sqldatasource

I have the following SqlDataSource

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:orangefreshConnectionString1 %>" 
        InsertCommand="INSERT INTO [Chat] ([Username], [Message]) VALUES (@Username, @Message)" 
        SelectCommand="SELECT [Id], [Username], [Message], [Date] FROM [Chat] ORDER BY [Id]" >
        <InsertParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="Message" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Date" Type="DateTime" /> 
            <asp:Parameter Name="Username" Type="String" />
        </InsertParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Which controls the following FormView:

```
<asp:FormView ID="FormView1" runat="server" DefaultMode="Insert"
        OnItemInserted="fv_ItemInserted" RenderOuterTable="False" 
            DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
        <InsertItemTemplate>
            <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server" DefaultButton="Button1">
            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" CssClass="chattxtbox"
            Text='<%# Bind("Message") %>' autocomplete="off"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" CommandName="insert" style="display:none" Text="Button" OnClick="insertUser"/>
            </asp:Panel>
        </InsertItemTemplate>
        </asp:FormView>
```

I want to be able a variable's content into the Username column, so on Button1 I set the following event: OnClick="insertUser"

```
 protected void insertUser(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string username1 = User.Identity.Name;
        SqlDataSource1.InsertParameters.Add("Username", username1);
        SqlDataSource1.Insert();
    }
```

This isn't working though, I don't get any SQL error message at all, is this the right way to do this? And where did I go wrong?

Comment: Are Message and Date required columns in your database ?

Comment: All columns are required

Comment: Can you try to add message parameter and see if it inserts ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change Insert `Parameter` to `SessionParameter`.

```
<InsertParameters>
   <asp:Parameter Name="Message" Type="String" />
   <asp:Parameter Name="Date" Type="DateTime" /> 
   <asp:Parameter Name="Username" Type="String" />
   <asp:SessionParameter Name="Username" SessionField="Username" Type="String" />
</InsertParameters>
```

And in Page_Load handler,

```
Session["Username"]=User.Identity.Name;
```

Comment: This sounds good, but still I get the same result... nothing happens. I thought this could be something on my FormView and pressing Enter maybe not triggering, but I just tried inserting from Textboxes and it all works fine.

Comment: Does it throws an exception? I think you should remove `Date` parameter because of this SQL statement - `INSERT INTO [Chat] ([Username], [Message]) VALUES (@Username, @Message)`

Comment: OK, seems like I was having some localhost conflict, this solution works very well, cheers man.

Answer (score 0):

Here you want to declare your parameter as a [Control Parameter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.controlparameter.aspx) and then you don't need to assign the value to the parameter in code. You can just call insert.

Comment: How would I assign User.Identity.Name as a value though?